# When do local isomorphisms extend to global isomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $U$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbf C$, and let $V\subset U$ be a dense open subvariety. Let $X\to U$ and $Y\to U$ be  smooth projective morphisms such that their restrictions to $V$ are isomorphic as morphisms over $V$.

When does such an isomorphism extend to an isomorphism of $X\to U$ and $Y\to U$ over $U$?

If $U$ is of dimension zero, there is nothing to say.

In other words, when is the morphism $$ Isom_U(X,Y) \to Isom_V(X\times_U V , Y\times_U V)$$ surjective?

I'm basically looking for a ``as general as it gets" statement.

Counterexamples are also very welcome.

Comment: Take $U$ equal to the affine line, $X=Y=\mathbb P^1_U$ and compute $\mathrm{Aut}_V(X\times_U V)$ for any open subset $V$ of $U$...

Comment: Ok. I didn't see this counterexample. Thank you very much. The answer should be PGL($A[V]$ if I understand correctly. And clearly PGL($\mathbf C[x]$) does not surject on PGL($\mathbf C[x]_x$).

Comment: For the positive direction, look for Matsusaka-Mumford theorem in a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample (**Edit**:  if $Y\to U$ is not assumed smooth).

Take $U=\mathbb A^2$ with origin $O$ ($O$ being an arbitrary rational point of $\mathbb A^2$),  $V=\mathbb A^2\setminus \{O\}$, $X=U$ with $X\to U$ the identity  and $Y\to U$ the blow-up of $O$ in $\mathbb A^2$ .
Note that $V\subset X$  and $V\subset Y$.
The identity $(X|V)=V\to (Y|V)=V$, which is a $V$- isomorphism, cannot be extended to a $U$-morphism $X\to Y$, let alone to a $U$-isomorphism.

Comment: Dear Georges, I think he's asking the morphism $Y\to U$ to be smooth.

Comment: Dear @Robert: you are right! I hadn't noticed the smoothness assumption on the structural morphisms. Let's say that my counterexample shows the necessity of some such assumption! Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Dear Georges: Yes, it is interesting that smoothness is required!